# Regular expression matching lines that are not commented out

Tags: python, regex, atom-editor

Given the following code

```
print("aaa")
#print("bbb")
# print("ccc")

def doSomething():
    print("doSomething")
```

How can I use regular expression in Atom text editor to find all the `print` functions that are not commented out? I mean I only want to match the `print`s in `print("aaa")` and `print("doSomething")`.

I've tried `[^#]print`, but this also matches the `print` in `# print("ccc")`, which is something that is not desired.

`[^# ]print` doesn't match any line here.

The reason I want to do this is that I want to disable the log messages inside a legacy project written by others.

Comment: Or just `^\s*print`. With multiline flag `m`.

Comment: I'd match horizontal spaces only and add a `(` for safety: [`^[ \t]*print\(.*`](https://regex101.com/r/dB1yI7/2) (`.*`  is redundant, just to match the whole rest of the line).

Comment: `^\s*print` also matches the space started from `doSomething():` all the way to `print("doSomething")`. I don't want to match the space after `doSomething():`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you confirm my first suggestion (`^(?![ \t]*#)[ \t]*print`) worked for you (I deleted that first comment), I believe you just want to find the `print` on single lines.

The `\s` matches any whitespace, incl. newline symbols. If you need to just match tabs or spaces, use a `[ \t]` character class.

Use

```
^[ \t]*print
```

or (a bit safer in order not to find any `printer`s):

```
^[ \t]*print\(
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I you want to match only the print (and not all arguments), you can use :

```
^\s*(print)
```

Comment: Thank you, @Spawnrider. But I found `^\s*(print)` also matches the spaces after `doSomething():` in Atom. [See here](http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=88e8f90)

Comment: And like this  ^\s*(print).+$ ?

Comment: Finally, I find `^(?![ \t]*#)[ \t]*print` is applicable in my case.

Comment: That is my first suggestion, BTW. However, I think it should be better to use `^[ \t]*print`. See my  answer.